# SonarQube overwrites ruleset and analyzers

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a C# project that uses the StyleCop.Analyzers (based on Roslyn). When we compile this project using msbuild 14, we see the following warning raised by StyleCop.Analyzers:

```
warning SA1005: Single line comment must begin with a space.
```

So far, so good. That's what we expect.

Then, we created a simple script that does this compilation within a SonarQube msbuild start/stop:

```
cd MyProjectRoot
"D:\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.0\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe" begin /k:test /n:test /v:1.0.0 /d:sonar.host.url=https://mysonar.com/ /d:sonar.login=abc
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Debug /t:Rebuild
"D:\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-2.0\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe" end
```

When we run this, we have something strange: we don't see the previous warning SA1005.

By looking at the msbuild output we see that when msbuild is **not** called within SonarQube start/stop, we have the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe ... /analyzer:..\packages\StyleCop.Analyzers.1.0.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Newtonsoft.Json.dll /analyzer:..\packages\StyleCop.Analyzers.1.0.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\StyleCop.Analyzers.CodeFixes.dll /analyzer:..\packages\StyleCop.Analyzers.1.0.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\StyleCop.Analyzers.dll
```

But when StyleCop is used **within** SonarQube start/stop, we have:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\csc.exe ... /analyzer:C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\1\.sonarqube\.static\csharp_1.11.0\SonarAnalyzer.zip\SonarAnalyzer.CSharp.dll /analyzer:C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\1\.sonarqube\.static\csharp_1.11.0\SonarAnalyzer.zip\SonarAnalyzer.dll
```

So as you can see, we are not using the same analyzers! In fact, I am not using my configured Analyzers at all. Furthermore, we are not using the same ruleset. I haven't shown it in the msbuild output, but you can trust me ;)

So two questions:

- How can we preserve our configured code Analyzers when compiling with SonarQube enabled?
- How can we preserve our configured RuleSet when compiling with SonarQube enabled?

Note that I am using:

- SonarQube msbuild runner 2.0
- SonarQube server 5.3
- SonarQube c# plugin 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube overrides the ruleset used during analysis. If you want your ruleset to be the same you will need to setup the quality profile in SonarQube to match your current ruleset. There is a VS plugin that will sync your ruleset from the SonarQube server to your local projects if you want to use it.

As for the StyleCop analyzer you need to package the analyzer by using the following SDK:  https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonarqube-roslyn-sdk/blob/master/README.md

Once you do that the rules should be available as Quality gate rules for use within sonar, and will run automatically during the analysis.

Comment: Wow this is complicated and hard to keep in sync with source control! In our real use case, we use custom analyzers that detect violation to our coding rules. We then use rulesets to disable some rules for parts of the code. The analyzer is in one of our nuget package. The master of the configuration just **can't** be sonar. It must be the source code as people will modify the ruleset + the version of the analyzer as they change their code. The workflow that SonarQube imposes is therefore not working for us.... it should be the other way around: Source control is master and SonarQube is slave.

Comment: After digging into the target files included by Sonar, my conclusion is that compiling with Sonar changes the msbuild options (ex: treat warning as errors is set to 'false' even though my project set it to 'true'). This is highly unwanted. My build process now does not behave the same when the sonar qube metrics are being capture :( A project using SonarQube should really be compiled twice. 1) compile it normally to generate your build artifact (ex: msi). 2) Rebuild it with SonarQube enabled. This makes sure that all the compilation settings set by your developers are not changed by SonarQube.

Comment: We don't use sonar the same way you do. We have a nightly build that just runs the sonar build and generate no artifacts. We have additional builds that generate artifacts etc. (basically sonar is on its own)

Comment: this is awful. As @mabead said, the source control should rule. I already sync the rules between source control and sonar, but sonar put everything as a warning, but in source control I have some of the rules as errors. Moreover, the analyzer from sonar does not take the stylecop.json http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310622/how-to-set-stylecop-json-creating-stylecop-anayzers-plugin-for-sonarqube