# How to set stylecop.json creating Stylecop Anayzers plugin for Sonarqube?

Tags: .net, json, plugins, sonarqube, stylecop

I want to use the rules of the StyleCop analyzer for Roslyn in SonarQube, In order to do that and following the documentation founded, I downloaded the SonarQube Roslyn SDK, and  I generate the plugin.

In my development environment I have a JSON file (stylecop.json) that add configuration:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/master/StyleCop.Analyzers/StyleCop.Analyzers/Settings/stylecop.schema.json",
  "settings": {
    "documentationRules": {
      "companyName": "XXXXXX",
      "copyrightText": " My Copyright (c) ",
      "xmlHeader": true,
      "fileNamingConvention": "metadata"
    },
    "namingRules": {
      "allowedHungarianPrefixes": ["as", "do", "id", "if", "in", "is", "my", "no", "on", "to", "ui"]
    }
  }
}
```

This configuration works perfectly with VS2015, but when I run the analysis, the plugin does not get it, I am aware that I do not setup that file when I create the plugin. I am able to recreate the plugin, but how do I setup that JSON file for the plugin creation process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roslyn analyzers can load parameters from files. This API is not too strict, meaning you can easily write an analyzer that requires a single file, multiple files, or whatever parameter loading that you can come up with. We haven't yet generalized this in the SonarQube Roslyn API, so there's no way to define additional files.

However, you can set up your projects to use your stylecop.json the same way as you'd do without SonarQube being in the picture. Then the SonarQube Scanner for MsBuild will pull down the analyzer DLLs from the SonarQube server, add them to your project during build, and with the latest version it will not clear the `AdditionalFiles` property, so your stylecop.json will be passed to the analyzers.

Comment: @tamas-sonarsource-team I assume that SonarQube Scanner for MsBuild will pull down the analyzer DLLs and take the json file, but it does not get the configuration. In Sonar appear code smells that does not appear in VS due the use of the JSON.

Comment: you talk about a property (AdditionalFiles) that property belongs to Sonar? to the Scanner? to the project?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. It belongs to the msbuild project. `AdditionalFiles` is a hardcoded property in MsBuild. Have a look here: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/EnableConfiguration.md

Comment: There's no way to specify the .json on the SonarQube server. It needs to be set up in the msbuild project.

Comment: I changed the tag to `AdditionalFiles` but I keep getting the same warnings: `field 'myParentSystem' must not use Hungarian notation`

Comment: when you say "latest version" you mean latest version of SonarQube or the runner?

Comment: My mistake, the AdditionalFiles tag works, I was changing in a different project